# setting up an SSL site with multiple bindings in IIS 8.5

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, http-redirect, iis-8.5

I am hoping you can help. I have 5 websites that run off the same .net code base and have different themes based on the url.

For example, http://site1.mydomain.co.uk is set up so that it does a http redirect to https://site1.mydomain.co.uk and I have the main SSL IIS entry as mydomain.co.uk with a wildcard SSL certificate and bindings for https://site1.mydomain.co.uk.

The issue I have though is when I put the http redirect on one of the other urls, all of them change to the last one entered. If that makes sense?

So, let's say I have just finished the site1.mydomain.co.uk entry and now move onto site2.mydomain.co.uk. I create the https://site2.mydomain.co.uk binding in the main mydomain.co.uk IIS record and then put a http redirect on http://site2.mydomain.co.uk so that it redirects to https://site2.mydomain.co.uk.

If I then go and check the previous record, site1.mydomain.co.uk the redirect has now changed to https://site2.mydomain.co.uk which is not what I wanted. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance you're using the same folder in the filesystem for all 5 websites?

In IIS, the HTTP Redirect settings are stored in a web.config file in the folder you're serving from, so if you were serving all 5 sites from the same folder then they would all have the same settings, i.e. changing the settings for one of them would change it for all of them.

That being said, I strongly recommend that you use URL Rewrite to do http to https redirects. Doing the redirect in this way is compatible with having 5 sites served from the same folder. You can install it from here (WARNING: the install requires an iisreset, i.e. a brief downtime for your site): http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

After installing URL Rewrite, you can create a rule to do the redirect. Stack Overflow won't let me post the screenshot here, so I uploaded it to here: http://postimg.org/image/4s4vjajs3/cf4f5c08/

Also, if you're using a wildcard certificate, then doing the redirect in this way might remove your need for having 5 different websites.